# AtomicReference getAndSet not working as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, atomicreference

I have a class called `LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse` that has two class members viz a `List<CustomClass> customClassList` and an `int` storing `hashCode()` of `customClassList`

I have atomic reference of above class defined in another class like,

```
private final AtomicReference<LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse> denyListAtomicReference;
```

which is being initialized in the constructor like this

```
this.denyListAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(new LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse(new ArrayList<>()));
```

I have this code in a method in same class thats updating atomic reference

```
try {
List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> newDenyList = sonarisConsumer. getSonarisSuggestions);
List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> validatedDenyList = validate (newDenyList); consumptionMetrics.addCount("denyListSize" , validatedDenyList.size), Unit.ONE);
setDenyListAtomicReference(validatedDenyList);
}
```

This is what setDenyListAtomicReference looks like

```
void setDenyListAtomicReference(List<IpBlockingDenyListRecords newDenyList) {
denyListAtomicReference.getAndSet(new LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse(newDenyList));
}
```

But when I call getIpBlockingDenyList

```
public List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> getIpBlockingDenyList() {
log.info("localDenyListSize: " + denyListAtomicReference.get() . getIpBlockingDenyList().size());
return denyListAtomicReference.get().getIpBlockingDenyList();
```

it returns an empty list.

I tried using `set` instead of `getAndSet`. Added bunch of log and debug statements but I am not able to understand why reference is not updating. I have confirmed that `validatedDenyList` holds the records as expected and is non empty.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When posting here, you may get a better response if you put some effort into devising a simplified example with an obvious problem domain rather dumping your actual domain. “IpBlockingDenyList…” etc. is a distraction, and makes your Question harder to read.

Comment: When posting here, follow Java conventions such as indenting the lines of code within a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multiple `AtomicReference#get` calls is *not* atomic

> it returns an empty list.

You have not included enough detail for us to diagnose this problem. However, I could *guess* that it may come from one huge mistake you made in your code: Calling `AtomicReference#get` twice.

In this block:

```java
public List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> getIpBlockingDenyList() {
    log.info("localDenyListSize: " + denyListAtomicReference.get().getIpBlockingDenyList().size());
    return denyListAtomicReference.get().getIpBlockingDenyList();
}
```

… you call `denyListAtomicReference.get()` twice. That pair of calls is *not* atomic. Consider this sequence of events:

| Sequence | Thread 101 (your code above) | Thread 27 (some other imaginary code) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `denyListAtomicReference.get()` returns list *x* |  |
| 2 |  | `denyListAtomicReference.set( y )` call changes the reference from list *x* to list *y* |
| 3 | `denyListAtomicReference.get()` returns list *y* |  |

In this scenario you would be reporting on the size of list *x* while handing off an entirely different list *y*.

You should change that block to call `get` only once.

```java
public List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> getIpBlockingDenyList() {
    List<IpBlockingDenyListRecord> list = denyListAtomicReference.get().getIpBlockingDenyList() ;
    log.info("localDenyListSize: " + list.size());
    return list;
}
```

---

### Don't call `get` if you don't want the value returned

Separate issue: Call `set` rather than `getAndSet` if you don't capture the returned value.

Your line:

```
denyListAtomicReference.getAndSet(new LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse(newDenyList));
```

… returns the old value contained in the atomic reference before setting a new value in the atomic reference. But you do not bother to capture a reference to the old value returned. So there is no point here in "getting". Just call `set` of you don't care about the old value.

```
denyListAtomicReference.set(new LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse(newDenyList));
```

---

### Alternate example

Let's rewrite your code for simplicity.

> I have a class called LocalIpBlockingDenyListResponse that has two class members viz a List customClassList and an int storing hashCode() of customClassList

Let's use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) for simplicity. Note that we guard our `List` property by ensuring it is immutable with call to `List.copyOf` combined with `new ArrayList`.

```java
package work.basil.example.atomics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public record People( List < String > list ,
                      int hash )
{
    public static People of ( final Collection < String > namesInput )
    {
        List < String > names = List.copyOf ( new ArrayList <> ( namesInput ) );
        return new People ( names , Objects.hashCode ( names ) );
    }

    public People
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull ( list );
        if ( Objects.hashCode ( list ) != hash ) throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Received an invalid hash code number" );
    }
}
```

Assign an object of that record class to an atomic reference. And then replace that reference several times in other threads. I believe this code will result in there never being an empty list.

```java
package work.basil.example.atomics;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class ListRef
{
    public final AtomicReference < People > peopleRef;

    public ListRef ( People peopleArg )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull ( peopleArg );
        this.peopleRef = new AtomicReference <> ( peopleArg );
    }

    public void replacePeople ( Collection < String > names )
    {
        People newPeople = People.of ( names );
        People oldPeople = this.peopleRef.getAndSet ( newPeople );
        String report = "Replaced " + oldPeople + " with " + newPeople + " at " + Instant.now ( );
        System.out.println ( report );  // Beware: System.out does NOT necessarily report its inputs in chronological order. Always include and study a timestamp.
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        People people = People.of ( List.of ( "Alice" , "Bob" ) );
        ListRef app = new ListRef ( people );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Demo beginning at " + Instant.now ( ) );
        List < List < String > > manyNames =
                List.of (
                        List.of ( "Carol" , "Davis" ) ,
                        List.of ( "Edith" , "Frank" ) ,
                        List.of ( "Gail" , "Harold" ) ,
                        List.of ( "Irene" , "Jack" ) ,
                        List.of ( "Karen" , "Lenard" )
                );
        try ( ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool ( 3 ) )
        {
            for ( List < String > names : manyNames )
            {
                Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 5 , 25 ) );
                ses.schedule (
                        ( ) -> this.replacePeople ( names ) ,
                        d.toSeconds ( ) ,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS
                );
            }
        }
        System.out.println ( "Demo ending at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Demo beginning at 2023-08-03T06:55:43.175423Z
Replaced People[list=[Alice, Bob], hash=1963929334] with People[list=[Karen, Lenard], hash=217763130] at 2023-08-03T06:55:51.215807Z
Replaced People[list=[Karen, Lenard], hash=217763130] with People[list=[Gail, Harold], hash=-2072015662] at 2023-08-03T06:55:52.185813Z
Replaced People[list=[Gail, Harold], hash=-2072015662] with People[list=[Irene, Jack], hash=-2094338259] at 2023-08-03T06:55:53.185362Z
Replaced People[list=[Irene, Jack], hash=-2094338259] with People[list=[Edith, Frank], hash=2139146613] at 2023-08-03T06:55:59.185048Z
Replaced People[list=[Edith, Frank], hash=2139146613] with People[list=[Carol, Davis], hash=2077047731] at 2023-08-03T06:56:07.182682Z
Demo ending at 2023-08-03T06:56:07.183702Z
```